# Help me identify this tablet and whether there are custom ROMs for it

Tags: rooting, zte-blade

I was gifted this one device that I can't find any information online on, despite exhaustive searching.
Internally, the tablet claims the following:

> - Model number: S7Q
> - Android version: 4.2.2
> - Kernel version: 3.0.36+ twp@server71 #525
> - Build number: S7Q_ZTE_PAD_EN.V2014.4

Naturally from this I would assume it is some ZTE device that would be called **S7Q** , but my searching of the internet only turned up that term a couple of times, both cases of a lone person on the XDA forum asking "what is this?" and getting no real answer. More searching seemed to suggest it was a Blade S7, but *Ask Mr Pigfish*, a software meant to identify a ZTE Blade model, reports that I have an "unknown model".

I'd really like to figure this one out so I could root it and setup a custom ROM, and I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: If search doesn't turn up anything, don't expect stuff for it.

Comment: See if you can find your device here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6154891?hl=en

Comment: That is an ZTE S7Q tablet, a "chinese" cheapy tablet. A quick search of XDA and SlateDroid yield nothing so the chances of finding ROMs or recovery for this device are near zero.

Comment: "S7Q" turns up nothing on that list.

Comment: @Morgmin: which means it is not supported by Google, adding to your problems as pointed out by others on changing OS